# Presenter vocal mic low end problems

Tags: lapel, microphone, eq, dynamics, techniques

Hi all, just a quick question.... Working on a live broadcast TV show about gardening with 3 presenters on wireless lapel mics...

2 of the 3 presenter's sound is all good, the third presenter which so happens to be the main presenter is really heavy in the low end and ive tried the obvious eq-ing to certain extents. rolling off the low end etc.. but his voice for some reason seems to still resonate a huge low end presence....

the mic is clipped, visibly, to his polo shirt second button from the top... at the top of his chest...

Any suggestions would be cool, we're on Episode 9 at the moment, its not a huge issue really that the director or anyone is complaining but you know we all like to be in control of the audio we are responsible for to be as professional as we can.

If he was presenting on his own actually would be really nice intimate almost.. but its the sheer contrast between the three of them..

Thanks for reading...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second Jesse's comment. The octave above the fundamental, which usually sits between 200-300 Hz is the 'box' frequency that presents so many problems.

This simple roll off + Notch should fix the problem. If this is still not working then first of all check the mic is working properly (perhaps swap the mics around the presenters) and if all else fails try some multi-band compression. Using only two bands you can mega compress the low endd while leaving everything else to have a more natural dynamic range.

Tread carefully with the multi-band. If you're not confident with it you could cause more a problem then you already have.

Best

Comment: I did try the swapping the mics around to see if the problems persists to which it does unfortunately, I only have a simple built into the desk compressor which isnt that extensive. But i'll try and investigate specifically the octave above the fundamental as you suggest. Thanks very much for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

Hey Chris, have you tried notching the 2nd or 3rd harmonic in the presenter's voice? I sometimes find that this creates more boomy-ness than the actual fundamental frequency. You can search for it using a boost with a high Q setting or use an EQ with a spectral analyzer such as Fabfilter Pro-Q. Also try hunting for some vocal clarity just below 2k and giving that a boost (avoid increasing syballance though)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, we dont really have any spectral analyzer until they get their financial boost in a few months. But i'll take your advice. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Chris, what happens when you move the mic another button down?

Comment: Hi Donna, thanks for your comment. Actually I did try this before and I remember that it made it worse. I'm thinking the low end resonance is coming directly from the cavity space of the chest. It seems to be a bit of minor pain.